# Why GWTTestCase only accept IsSerializable interface for serializing java objects?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, serialization, integration-testing, gwttestcase

I have several model class that implement `java.io.Serializable` interface (for serialization purpose) and they work perfectly in devmode and webmode but when i want to use them in a GWTTestCase after running test i get this error:

```
Type 'com.saeed.test.model.MyModel' was not assignable to 
'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable'
and did not have a custom field serializer.
For security purposes, this type will not be deserialized.
```

I mention that MyModel class does not have default constructor(but works perfectly in devmode and webmode).

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Please post an update whether you were able to solve the problem. It is a nice practice to close the question if it gets solved either by choosing an answer or by posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through GWT RPC's user test suite [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc) and rpc test suite [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/rpc/client%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

You might also have to follow how GWT sets up its RPC tests.